# How to retrieve value from previous activity with click the button using json php?

Tags: android

i'm newbie to android program..I find some error in my final project tour travel app...i want to make listview that contain hotel list, then if listview was clicked will show detail hotel..ok..it works..
On detail hotel page there is a button "CEK KAMAR", it's used to show listview of room hotel based on ID hotel..i got stuck on this part..the listview has showed but all room class of all hotels..i can't filter the listview based on ID hotel..so..i really need help...thanks advance..

For more clear explanation, hereby i enclosed the screenshot app..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: how is this related to JavaScript,PHP,MySQL and JSON?

Comment: I think this is what you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android

Comment: @Ard My best guess on the tags: It isn't, they're just for more visibility.

Comment: Nice pics don't replace code